# What impact does having multiple domain names for a site, have on SEO rankings?

Tags: seo

I have searched but not really found anything clear on the matter from what I have read so far, what impact does having your domain name across multiple tlds (e.g. mycompany.com and mycompany.fr and mycompany.es) have on your rankings?? I'm being told having them point to the same content is likely to get the site shot down by google.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for SEO advice. It might be on-topic on [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google doesn't have a parked domain detector according to Matt Cutts, so if the domain names simply all point to one location it won't hurt you.

However, if you have duplicate content that's another story. In your example it sounds like you might have multiple sites that all have the same content, but are different domain names.

Matt Cutts, the head of Google's Webspam team, claims that duplicate content will not hurt your ranking. You can watch that [video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mQZY7EmjbMA)

He gives the disclaimer that it can hurt if it's "spammy" without going into very specific detail what that actually means. In my experience (I've had about 5-6 clients that did this) Google would typically look at one of their domains and ignore the duplicates, but not hurt their main site. The only exception to this is if one of the sites that isn't your main one starts getting more backlinks or traffic and then Google sees it as more relevant and then ignores your main site's content... Google's going to favor the duplicate that appears the most relevant.

I'm pretty cautious about duplicate content though because it has the possibility of hurting your site if Google thinks it's "spamy" and they change their algorithm so frequently now that its hard to keep up.

My recommendation is set up the other domain names as parked domains instead of duplicating the site. As you build up any backlinks focus on linking to just one domain name too.

Comment: No The names just point to the same content. But thanks for your explanation.

Comment: If you have them as permanent redirects (ie you type in domain2.com and your address bar changes to domain.com) then you're usually fine, but it doesn't seen to help you any either.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if these serve the same content, it will sooner or later trigger a content issue or some kind of manually penalty. If Google finds out you own all those domain names (or they belong to a small network of owners), then they will take action for sure. The penalty will sink you in SERPs.

It is not natural to have many domain names sharing the same content. It does not happen by accident and there is no good reason one would need to achieve this.

Comment: The client is just worried as he's buying the tld domain names for his business. I read somewhere since posting my question, that I should setup a 301 from the other tlds to the primary tls (i.e. ".com => .fr" for example) and that's fine by google. There is no duplication of content  at all.

Answer (score 0):

I would never recommend using different ccTLDs for the same content in the same languages.

However, if the websites are localized, you can use hreflang and "connect" each version of a page with appropriate language. Check this link: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en